# Xcode: UI Automation: waitForValid()

Tags: ios, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

There's a waitForInvalid() but what about a waitForValid() function? For some reason, push/popTimeout doesn't work for me in many cases. Apple?

Answer (score 6):

If the element is "valid" but not "visible" that might return too early.  This should wait until its visible and valid.

```
UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(20);
window.navigationBar().name()["Welcome"].withValueForKey(1, "isVisible");
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

or

```
UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(20);
window.navigationBar().name().firstWithPredicate("name is 'Welcome' and isVisible == '1'")
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

Answer (score 4):

When you try to access a particular element directly, there is a default wait time of 5 seconds. You can change the default time as follows.

```
UIATarget.localTarget().pushTimeout(20);
window.navigationBar().name()["Welcome"];
UIATarget.localTarget().popTimeout();
```

This will make your instruments wait up to 20 seconds until the name of the navigation bar has changed to "Welcome."

Comment: Yes, I did this, but it wasn't work. It must've been a UIAutomation issue.