# xcode - Add delay to instruments script

Tags: xcode, instruments, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

How do you add a delay in an Xcode Instruments UI script? I have a view that can take a second to load. I have tried these waitForValid suggestions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350925/xcode-ui-automation-waitforvalid) but I can't get it to work because I don't really have an object to check. Can I wait for a storyboard ID to show up?

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found within Apple documentation. I somehow missed it, and feel sheepish.

```
UIATarget.localTarget().delay(X);
```

Having X in seconds.

[UsingtheAutomationInstrument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)

Answer (score 0):

Or,do you use an activity indicator to show the loading progress?

Then maybe you can check the visibility of [UIAActivityIndicator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAActivityIndicatorClassReference/UIAActivityIndicator/UIAActivityIndicator.html).